# Retrofit Malformed URL

Tags: retrofit2

I want to use telegram api with retrofit. But it gives

"Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed URL. Base: https://api.telegram.org/, Relative: botXXXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/getUpdates" error

```
 public interface telegramService {
    @GET ("{botKey}/getUpdates")
    Call<telegramModel> getValue (@Path("botKey") String botKey);
 }

    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.telegram.org/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .build();
    Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(client).build();
    telegramService mTelegram =retrofit.create(telegramService.class);
    Call<telegramModel> mTelegramModel= mTelegram.getValue("botXXXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Call<telegramModel> mTelegramModel= mTelegram.getValue("/botXXXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
```

Note the leading `/`